# QBXML, QBFC - Customer Statement

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, qbxml, qbfc

I may be missing something in the OSR, but what query do I use to retrieve a customer statement? I cant seem to identify the right query.

Would greatly appreciate some insight.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the QuickBooks APIs (QBFC and QBXML included) support fetching customer statements.

You could probably build your own by querying for the customers invoices, payments, etc. and displaying the summary data.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using ITransactionQuery, which gets a list of all the transactions for the company, which can be filtered to a customer.